# jQuery animation from left to right with gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Please have a look at the reference site (https://gperrine.wixsite.com/yy-samples). You can see the blue lines animate from left to right. I need exactly that animation in jQuery code with same gap . Someone please help. Reference https://gperrine.wixsite.com/yy-samples

Code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var j = 10;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('.target').append('<div class="test" id="div' + i + '" style="margin-right: '+j+'px" />');
    j = j - 1;
  }
});
```

```css
div.test {
  width: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #253f80;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  height: 70px;
}
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: @FaisalRamzan: Not in the comment. Edit your question and add your code using the Code Snippet feature

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery animate to animate the div.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var j = 10;
  var incremenetby = 20;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('#div'+i).css("left", j+"px");
    j = j + incremenetby;
    incremenetby -= 1;
  }
});

window.setTimeout(animateMe(), 1000);

function animateMe(){
  var j = 100;
  var incremenetby = 20;
  for (let i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('#div'+i).delay(j).animate({left: "+=100"},500);
    j+=100;
  }
}
```

```css
div.test {
  width: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #253f80;
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  height: 70px;
  position:absolute;
}
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target">
  <div class="test" id="div0"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div3"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div4"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div5"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div6"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div7"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div8"></div>
  <div class="test" id="div9"></div>
</div>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/4poazrc5/)

Comment: Great! thank you. what if we have to generate dynamic div(s) using jQuery like 10 to 50 ? and starts from left screen to right we screen auto calculated not just left: 100px ? can we do that ?

Comment: The effect should float in from the left side to the right side -- right now it is just shifting slightly to the right. Can you please help in this ?

Comment: I didn't hear from you again?

Comment: We cannot animate div with float. So we have to use left position.